# nested list from different modals in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this viewmodal which helps me to display data from two different modals

```
public class stdmov_viewmodal
    {
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
```

The view is as below

```
@model CodFirst.Models.stdmov_viewmodal

 <h2>Students</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Students)
        {
            @Html.DisplayName("student name: ") @item.fname   <br />

        }
        <h2>Songs</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
        {
           @Html.DisplayName("Movie name: ") <br />
        }
```

WIth this i am able to display student name and movie name separately.
But what if i want to display as student ABC have watched movies mov1,mov2,mov3.

I tried this

```
<ul>
 @foreach (var item in Model.student)
            {
 <li>@item.fname
 <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
            {
     <li>@item.name<li>
<ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could create a view model which represents what you want to display - e.g `StudentVM` containing the required properties for `Student` and an additional property `List<Movie> MoviesWatched { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your movies result as below:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.student)
{
    <li>
        @item.fname
        <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Movies.Where(movie => movie.WatchedByCollection.Any(wbc => wbc.Name == item.fname)))
        {
            <li>@item.name<li>
        }
        <ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```